# How to get scss variables in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

It's probably a stupid question, but I've already spent half a day. How do I get the color value of the $pink variable?

My broken code:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-palette: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette);


.aircraft-table{
   width: 800px;
  .mat-row{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .mat-row, .mat-cell{
     border-width: 0;
  }
  .mat-row:hover .mat-cell{
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-palette, '200');;
  }
}
```